# .Net App very slow on Windows 2012

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5

Have developed a console app which should run under 16 millisecs in production.

Runs fine in development machine (8 - 9 ms) with Intel I7 Processor, 16GB RAM and runs fine on other desktop machines (12-13 ms).

But only when moved to Windows 2012 machine with Xeon processor
OS: Windows Server 2012, 64 bit
CPU: Intel Xeon E5-2643 v2 @3.50 GHz (2 processors)
RAM: 32 GB

It slows down to 21-23 milli secs.  Same with multiple Windows 2012 & 2008 servers we have. (All Xeon powered processors)

It uses Math.Net DDL's doing some matrices calculations.

Any ideas to improve performance would be really helpful.

Tried ngen, x64 compilation, server power options (Highperformance) etc.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What other jobs are these servers doing? Are they busy?

Comment: How many times are you running the test to get those timings?  Lots of things could cause a 5 millisecond difference.

Comment: No other jobs are running on those servers.

Comment: These tests are being run for more than 2 days now.

Comment: Are you running the exe from the debug or release folder?  You should use the exe version and make sure the timestamp matches the build timestamp.

Comment: It is build as release version and deployed on production server.

Comment: Have you tried using a sampling profiler to see where it is taking it's time? A profiler in sampling mode should not add more than a few % of overhead and you don't need to let it run for very long.

Comment: Different JIT version? 4.6 has RyuJTI.

Comment: Tried profiling; costly calls are in Math.Net Matrices multiplications.  But same is running good on desktop machines.  What might be wrong with Win 2012 and 2008?

Comment: How can you categorically blame the OS here. Cpu or memory could be to blame.

Comment: (Not blaming any OS, rephrased) : Tried profiling; costly calls are in Math.Net Matrices multiplications. But same is running good on desktop machines. What I might be missing on Win 2012 and 2008?

Comment: Determining why an app is slow based on hardware specs doesn't really make sense. You should profile the app and figure out where time is spent.

Comment: Math.Net [uses Intel MKL](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/MKL.html) The newest version of MKL (11.3) doesn't have Server 2012 on the [supported OS list](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl-113-system-requirements). The test: Take a dev machine, install server 2012, run the app. If it works anyway, this isn't the problem, but you know there's something specific to that hardware that's causing it.

Comment: Have tried "RyuJTI" too, no much luck.  @theB will try MKL if that helps.

Comment: There is no performance gain using MKL.  But another simple sample program of a 200*200 matrix inverse and multiply it by another improved by 20 times in speed.  But the main application has many small matrices operations, but not as big as 200*200.  Does this makes a difference? Any ideas.